# Fire NSTimer when in sleep

Tags: ios, nstimer

I have a NSTimer that counts down and fires a method when it reaches 0. But when I press the sleep button on an iPhone it halts the timer and continues it when I reawaken the iPhone.

Is there a possibility that the NSTimer also fires when the iPhone is in "sleep" - similar to the Timer-Function in the default Time-App?

Or can I "fake" sleep mode so that the screen darkens and the timer continues?

Thanks

Comment: there are only three services what can run in the background: `location tracking`, `VoIP` or `audio`. generally every other thread will be suspended when the application goes to background or the phone goes to the sleep mode.* _(*this sentence does not cover every details, for the exact explanation, please, read the Apple's relevant documentation.)_

Comment: But how does an app like Serenity from taptaptap add the sleep timer (that stops playing after a certain time) that also fires if the iPhone is "sleeping"?

Comment: it does definitely not use any `NSTimer` for it because of the reason what I've written above but the `audio` services can run in the background smoothly. that is possible.

Comment: From what I understand I can't fire a method using UILocalNotification until the user taps a button on the notification itself. which is beside the point for my purpose.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can keep a timer running by explicitly stating to run it in a background task providing that the timer is no longer than Apple's specified background task time limit.  I remember reading that this is approx. 10 mins.

See the docs here under the section "Executing a Finite-Length Task in the Background"
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html